# Why is "from" used in "from henceforth"?

Tags: archaicisms, early-modern-english, redundancy

The dictionaries unanimously include the word ***from*** in their definitions of ***henceforth***:
e.g.

> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/henceforth): ***from*** this point on
>
> - *Henceforth*, supervisors will report directly to the manager.
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/henceforth): starting ***from*** this time:
>
> - *Henceforth*, the said building shall be the property of Brendan Duggan.
>
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/henceforth): ***from*** this time onwards
>
> - We were finally released with a formal warning that we were *henceforth* barred from the base.

So it strikes me as redundant to say ***from henceforth***. Yet I see it used a few times used in the KJV Bible. For example

> <sup>[***KJV** Luke 5:10*](https://biblehub.com/kjv/luke/5-10.htm)</sup> And Jesus said unto Simon, Fear not; ***from henceforth*** thou shalt catch men.

Not surprisingly, Shakespeare also uses it in [*Henry IV*](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Play.aspx?Act=1&Scene=3&WorkId=33#232756):

> I will ***from henceforth*** rather be my Selfe,
> Mighty, and to be fear'd, then my condition.

[FreeDictionary](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Henceforth) records an instance in a legal text:

> He said pending the coming into effect of the amendment, Chambers, ***from henceforth***, dispenses with the requirement of such service on it.

Is there an explanation for this redundant use? English seems to me a language that avoids redundancy when it can, and *henceforth* can clearly stand on its own. Then, why the *from* in ***from henceforth***?

Note that I am very interested in antiquated language and will not mind if the explanation includes outdated examples (I would even encourage it).

Note: I hadn't noticed it before, but I see that the same problem also occurs with other words like *[whence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whence), [thence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thence)* and *[hence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hence)*, or their compounds. Although they all contain the idea of ***from***, they are seen used together with ***from***.

Comment: Certain regions tend to omit 'of' in say "He looked out the window" but include it after 'inside' before a NP.

Comment: Another one is _whence_, which supposedly means _from where_, but Psalm 121 has 'from whence'.

Comment: @KateBunting The thing is, both "henceforth" and "whence" are also used on their own in the Bible. Which makes me wonder even more...

Comment: Shakespeare used [both](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/SearchResults.aspx?search=henceforth&WholeWordSearch=true), but with *from* much less often.

Comment: None of your three contemporary dictionary definitions uses “from henceforth.” The *from* is part of the definition.

Comment: @Xanne That makes my point. "From" is contained already in the definition of "henceforth", so why use both "from" and "henceforth"? As if saying "from from this point on"...

Comment: [Garner](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Garner_s_Modern_English_Usage/l2LmCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=garner+from+henceforth&pg=PA460&printsec=frontcover):   "**From henceforth.** This phrase is an ARCHAISM that the OED records as having last been current in the 17th century. Today the word *from* ought to be rooted out of the phrase--e.g..." and gives modern instances with the *from.*

Answer (score 1):

*Hence* is part of an old paradigm in English:

> Locative     Ablative       Dative
> *(at                                    from                              to)*
> ***Here         Hence         Hither***
> ***There      Thence      Thither***
> ***Where   Whence   Whither***

As such, it means a near (not far -- that would be *thence*) and known (not unknown -- that would be *whence*) place (or point in time) **from** which  some path (or  some length of time) is to be measured. It is therefore a proper object of *from* (that's the "ablative" sense). The phrase *from hence forth* thus means *from this time forth*. As usual, the phrase has been shortened by chopping off the preposition, leaving only two old words with odd senses, which makes it a better fixed phrase.

Comment: I've not seen "locative/ablative/dative" (Latin declension terms) applied to the here/there paradigm before. Is there a standard textbook that adopts those terms, because they're really not accurate!

Comment: No, they're just indications for those who want formal terms. The prepositions are just as accurate.